# Cypress - Status: 401 - Unauthorized in token authentication to other API call

Tags: api, token, cypress

I would like to ask for your help regarding the authentication token to be used in other API calls.
Below are the scripts of the command and test case:

```
//command.js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => { 
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: Cypress.env('api_auth'),
  body: {
    email: Cypress.env('email'),
    password: Cypress.env('password'),
 }
 })
 .its('body')
 .then(body => {
  cy.window().then(win => win.localStorage.setItem('jwt', body.token))
 })

//test case
describe('GET Data', ()=> {
before(() => {
    cy.login();
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
  });

it('GET - View All Data', () =>{
    cy.request({
        method : 'GET',
        url : Cypress.env('api_data'),
    }).then((res) =>{
        expect(res.status).equal(200)
    })
})
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Hi, @MasoudKeshavarz I got an error 401 while running the test case seems the token has not been applied.

Answer (score 0):

In my approach i have the same command, but instead of storing the token in the local storage, I'm adding it to the cypress.env file in the object of the admin, because i have several admins so my object file goes like so

```
{
admins: 
admin1:{
"username":"admin1",
"password": "123456",
"token":""
},
admin2:{
"username":"admin1", 
"password": "123456",
"token":""
 }
}
```

This way you can store several admins/user tokens and just attach as:

> Cypress.env.admins.admin1.token
> or
> Cypress.env.admins.admin2.token

I think this approach is simpler and in about 300 tests i've seen no problems regarding speed of the test execution or anything other